# Outline text xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, outline

I have long been trying to find an answer to the question of how to make a outline like to [image: Outline Text example]
Maybe someone here knows how to do this?

Comment: There's nothing I know of in XF that would do this, you'd have to make a custom renderer somehow. Why not just do this via assets?

Comment: SkiaSharp is the best bet.

Answer (score -2):

```
Use <frame OutlineColor="#000"><label Text="Settings"></label><frame>
```

Comment: `  <Frame                 
               OutlineColor="Black">
                    <Label 
                        Text="Rank" 
                        TextColor="#9278A5"
                        FontSize="39"
                        FontFamily="upheaval_pro_regular.otf#Upheaval Pro"                                       
                        />
                </Frame>`